# Is my website more vulnerable if API website gets hacked?

Tags: web-services, security, web

Say I have a website that is pulling data from Constant Contact or Mailchimp through their API. Then for some unfortunate reason, one of these websites get hacked. Is my site now more vulnerable to an attack since I am connected through an API?

Comment: What do you mean by "attack"? Would the hacker modifying data you pull from be an attack, or do you define attack as the hacker targeting your website specifically?

Comment: I am concerned about a hacker targeting my website specifically.

Answer (score 0):

Well on the surface it doesn't make your site less secure, as you are just requesting data from an external compromised data source.

However, if the API data source has been comprised the hackers could send data via the API which you might save to your database or display on your site, so hackers could potentially insert malicious scripts into your database or cause some reputational damage by sending all sorts of crap data (swear words, advertise porn sites etc) which you will display on your site.

In general the more complexity you add to any system (real life or virtual), the more ways it can be exploited, so it is always good to do some homework before you introduce any library or dependencies to your codebase.

*EDIT*
To add the above, OWASP do a great job by laying out all the risks with using a compromised API. 
https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2017-A9-Using_Components_with_Known_Vulnerabilities

Answer (score 0):

A targeted attack would be possible but unlikely. When using an API you are making requests to some server, which inherently gives that server information on who you are in order to send a response back. With that, a hacker could use that information to attempt and send an attack to your address. This could be done by either using your address for an external program/script, or by sending malicious information back as a response instead of what was intended.

This entire scenario though is highly unlikely to ever occur though for many reasons. The main reason is, why would a hacker targeting specifically you go through trouble of taking control of another entity, their API, then attack you? It'd be much more likely for the hacker to attempt to gain access to the API owner's database and exploit information held there, rather than target people using their API.

So yes, if a hacker gained access to an API you use, there exists a chance they could make a targeted attack on you as well. Mind you that this chance exists with any foreign entity you connect with. Providing an entity information about who you are and where you are will always create some chance of an attack.